# Roots of a polynomial inside the unit circle

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $k$ be a even positive integer. Now, consider the polynomial 
$$
p(x)=x^k-px^{k-1}-qx^{k-2}-x^{k-3}-\cdots -x-1,
$$
with $p$ and $q$ integers satisfying $q-1>p\geq 1$.

How to prove that this polynomial has k-2 roots inside the unit circle (there are two roots outside this circle by using the Descarte sign rule and the intermediate value theorem).

Any suggestion? I tried to use Rouché theorem, but without success.

Comment: Why do you think it does have $k-2$ roots inside the circle?

Comment: By using computational methods, we have two roots outside and the remaining are inside (I did for k=4, 1\leq p<q\leq 11). Do you think the contrary?

Comment: My real question is: is this a homework assignment? This site is not for hope with homework...

Comment: Any question we ask here people thinks are homework. This kind of problem was studied by Schur, Cohn, Pellet, etc. For example, for $p\geq q$ there are some methods related to a Kakeya paper which ensures only one root outside the unit circle. So, if you don't know how to help, please don't ask these things.

Comment: @Jean, Anyone can ask anything, since "The query is the piety of the mind" "Zartosht".

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz thanks! Do you have any idea to this problem?

Comment: What do you mean the inside of the unit circle? Is the boundary of the unit circle as the inside of this circle or not?

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz it means that they are in the interior of the circle.

Comment: why close this question?!

Comment: The conjecture is true for $u:=q-p>k-1$, just use Rouche' for $|x|=1$ with $g(x)=-q x^{k-2}$ and $f(x)=p(x)-g(x)$.
 More generally the number of zeroes in the closed unit disk seems to be $k-1$ for real $0\leq u \leq 1$ and $k-2$ for $u>1$ (but I can prove it
 only for $u=0$).

Answer (score 5):

The conjecture is not true for the case where $k$ is odd. The smallest degree polynomial which gives contradiction is as follow:

$$x^7-x^6-3x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1,$$

Where we have $k=7$, $p=1$ and $q=3$. If the claim is true, we must have $5$ roots in the interior of the unit circle. But, three roots of the above polynomial are as follows:
$$-1, -1, 2.479561783.$$

Actually, there are infinite counterexamples for the case where $k$ is odd. Two of them are as follows:
$$x^9-x^8-3x^7-x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1$$
with three roots
$$-1.071441460, -1., 2.480930101$$

and 
$$x^{13}-x^{12}-3x^{11}-x^{10}-x^9-x^8-x^7-x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3-x^2-x-1$$
with three roots
$$-1.130681001, -1., 2.481187340.$$

If we assume that the unit circle is closed (it contains its boundary), I did not have any counterexample until yet. I think in this case the claim may be true for odd and even $k$.

I will try to study the case where $k$ is even.

Comment: The OP requires $k$ to be *even*, I think

Comment: @YemonChoi: you are right. I did not care to the parity of $k$. It is strange why this answer got three up vote. So, I just edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $k$ is even is crucial because for such it is obvious there are only two real roots, one negative and one positive (for $x < -1$, using $y=-x$, it is easy to see the decomposition into the sum of two increasing polynomials, namely the first three terms and the rest, which start negative at -1 and go to $+\infty$ by the evenness condition on $k$, while it is obvious $p$ is negative between -1 and 0, as well as having one "large" root for positive $x$ as $p$ is a Cauchy polynomial and the positive root is largest of all roots in absolute value for such)

Since for the limiting case $q=p+1$, $x+1$ factors and we remain with a polynomial for which the Kakeya theory applies and we can conclude that it has one large positive root and all other roots inside the unit circle, a strategy for solving this would be to fix the coefficient $p>1$ and then show that for $q>p+1$, $q$ real, the corresponding polynomial has no roots on the unit circle, then use homotopy of polynomials (the existence of topological degree etc) to conclude that all such have same number roots inside/outside and then the limiting case gives us the solution since for $q=p+1$, $p>1$ we have a root outside, one on the circle and the rest strictly inside.

Comment: What is "Kakeya theory"?

Comment: @Glorfindel please explain me which Kakeya result to use, because the usual Kakeya-Enestrom theorem only holds for showing that all roots are inside some disk, but for polynomials with positive coefficients in some specific order. Could you please clarify me that? Thanks

Comment: @Jean sorry, I didn't write this answer, I only improved the formatting.

Comment: @Conrad could you please explain me better which Kakeya result you are talking about. I think there is some problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be true in the stronger assumption $q>p+2$, but I suspect it could be false for integer $p\ge1$ and $q=p+2$, and an even $k$. Let me explain why -it could be possibly useful to make either a counterexample, or a proof of the statement, at your taste.  Consider the equivalent statement, that the reciprocal polynomial $$Q(x):=-1+px+(p+2)x^2+x^3+\dots+x^k$$
has no  zeros in the closed unit disk, besides the two real zeros in the interval $(-1,1)$ (coming from $Q(-1)=1$, $Q(0)=-1$, $Q(1)=2p+k-1>0$).

A zero $x$ of $Q$ on the unit circle would solve 
$$-1+(p-1)x+(p+1)x^2={x-z\over x-1}$$
with $z=x^{k+1}$. The linear fractional transformation on the RHS maps the unit circle $|z|=1$ to a circle of radius ${1\over |x-1|}$ passing by $0$ and $1$, namely $\partial B\Big({x\over x-1},{1\over |x-1|}\Big)$.  Now it seems there are many $x\in\partial B(0,1)$, such that the trinomial at the LHS lies on the circle $\partial   B\Big({x\over x-1},{1\over |x-1|}\Big)$. For instance $x=-1$ is one of these, but it could well be a point with a dense orbit $\{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. In this case it could be possible, or quite hard to rule out, that for some even $k$  one has $z=x^k$, making $x$ a further zero of the corresponding $Q=Q_k$.

Comment: Actually I almost changed my mind, an I think now that  in the above lines one should check if it is true that  $$-1+(p-1)x+(q-1)x^2=t{x-z\over x-1 }$$ has no solution for $0\le t\le1$ and $|x|=1$,$x\neq-1$,  which would imply   the OP's conjecture.

Comment: Yes, I also think so. But I don't have idea how to attack this problem. I thought in considering the polynomial $f(x)$ (in the OP's statement) for the case $q=p+1$ where $x=-1$ is a root and write $F(x)=f(x)/((x+1)(x-\alpha))$, where $\alpha$ is the other root outside the unit circle.

Comment: I think it is not hard to prove that $q<\alpha<q+1/(q+1)$ (or something similar). Now consider the polynomial $t(x)=(x-\delta)(x+\epsilon)F(x)$ and so to prove that for some $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ very "near" to $1$, this polynomial has the form $x^k-c_{k-1}x^{k-1}-\cdots -c_1x-c_{0}$, where the $c_i$ are positive. So, a well-known result yields that all roots of such a polynomial are inside the circle with radius $\max\{|\epsilon|,|\delta|\}$. This is only heuristic argument, but I don't realized the complete proof.

Comment: ...For instance, it is easy to see that the equation for x and z I wrote in comment above has no solution in your assumptions, for $x=e^{i\alpha}$ with $0\le\alpha\le7\pi/32$, just because the imaginary part of the RHS is larger than the imaginary part of the RHS, for all |z|=1. One can further extend this interval of non-existence of solutions, but covering all $0\le\alpha\le\pi$ needs to look quite carefully.